# Selenium: click menu in dropdown not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select element of this HTML:

```
<div class="ddsd-body-box corplat-scrollbar"><div class="ddsd-top-inner-boxes-wrapper"><div class="tips-box-wrapper"><div class="css-mxf0ij-unf-ticker eneo4yd0"><div class="css-tfd7c3 eneo4yd1" style="transform: translateX(0%);"><div aria-label="unf-ticker-item" class="css-1gklkud eneo4yd2"><p class="css-1hjz1j2-unf-heading e1qvo2ff8"><span class="tips-box-wrapper__ticker-text"><span>Perkiraan tiba dihitung sejak pesanan dikirim.</span></span></p></div></div></div></div></div><div class="ddsd-options-wrapper"><div class="ddsd-option " data-testid="optionDuration-1104" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="ddsd-option__flex"><div class="ddsd-option__col-left"><div class="ddsd-option__service-name">Reguler (2-4 hari)</div></div><div class="ddsd-option__col-right"><div>Rp18.000 - Rp20.000</div></div></div></div><div class="ddsd-option " data-testid="optionDuration-1204" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="ddsd-option__flex"><div class="ddsd-option__col-left"><div class="ddsd-option__service-name">Reguler (5-9 hari)</div></div><div class="ddsd-option__col-right"><div>Rp18.000</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Mycode:

```
pilih = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ddsd-option']"))
pilih.select_by_visible_text("Reguler (2-4 hari)")
```

what's wrong with my code? why can't you click element? i really appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @DebanjanB not working click select opsi Reguler

Comment: How do you conclude that it's _not working_

Answer (score 0):

first of all your xpath used by you is not correct as it would not locate any element. As none of div have exact class name as "**ddsd-option**".  You must be getting **selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException**.

Also for select class to work element type must be an SELECT tag. Please see below documentation at selenium python official website:. 7.3.4

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

**7.34. Select Support class**
selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select(webelement)
Bases: object
**init**(webelement) Constructor. A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an
UnexpectedTagNameException is thrown.